# Memory leak in a custom Handler when re-creating fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-memory

The following is a stripped down version of a `Fragment` I'm using to display a simple stopwatch. The app is working perfectly on a tablet. However, on a phone, where an orientation change will cause the fragment to be re-created in a new activity, I'm getting a memory leak.

```
public class TimerFragment extends BaseFragment {

    private static final int MESSAGE_UPDATE_TEXT = 0;

    private TextView text;

    private static final String KEY_START_TIME = "KEY_START_TIME";
    private static final String KEY_ELAPSED_TIME = "KEY_ELAPSED";

    private long startTime;
    private long elapsedTime;

    private static boolean running;

    private final TimerHandler handler = new TimerHandler(this);

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        setUpHomeButton(false);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timer, container, false);

        text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timerText);

        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            startTime = savedInstanceState.getLong(KEY_START_TIME);
            elapsedTime = savedInstanceState.getLong(KEY_ELAPSED_TIME);
        }

        if(running) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(timer);
            handler.postDelayed(timer, 0);
        }

        updateText();

        return view;
    }

    private void updateText() {
        if(elapsedTime == 0L) {
            text.setText("0:00");
            return;
        }

        int sec = (int) (elapsedTime / 1000);
        int min = sec / 60;
        sec = sec % 60;

        text.setText(min + ":" + sec);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        handler.removeCallbacks(timer);

        outState.putLong(KEY_START_TIME, startTime);
        outState.putLong(KEY_ELAPSED_TIME, elapsedTime);
    }

    private final Runnable timer = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            elapsedTime = now - startTime;

            running = true;
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(MESSAGE_UPDATE_TEXT);
        }
    };

    private static class TimerHandler extends Handler {
        private final WeakReference<TimerFragment> weakFragment;

        public TimerHandler(TimerFragment f) {
            weakFragment = new WeakReference<TimerFragment>(f);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            TimerFragment fragment = weakFragment.get();
            switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_UPDATE_TEXT:
                if(fragment != null) {
                    fragment.updateText();
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Eclipse MAT even gives me this:

```
One instance of "android.os.MessageQueue" loaded by "<system class loader>" occupies 1     529 600 (14,19%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "android.os.Message"     loaded by "<system class loader>".

Keywords
android.os.Message
android.os.MessageQueue
```

However, the above does not appear when I analyze memory when running on a tablet (single activity at all times).

Any ideas for how to fix this? If I understand the problem correctly, which I might not, I think there are multiple handlers getting created when an orientation change happens on a phone.

If my problem is hard to understand give me a hint and I will try to explain better.

Comment: try to call `handler.removeCallbacks(timer);` in `onDestroyView`

Comment: You solved it! Surprisingly simple.. thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple rule you should always follow when using `Handler`. Every time you write `handler.postDelayed` you should also write `handler.removeCallbacks` somewhere.

In your case you are calling `handler.postDelayed(timer, 0)` in `onCreateView` method so `onDestroyView` is the most appropriate place to call `handler.removeCallbacks(timer)`